# Can an __init__ automatically execute code after calling super?

Tags: python

I have something like this:

```
class SuperClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # initialization stuff

    def always_do_this_last(self):
        # cleanup stuff


class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # intermediate stuff
        self.always_do_this_last()
```

Is it possible to automatically call that last line? Every subclass of `SuperClass` needs perform the cleanup.

Comment: it looks like the perfect job for a context manager ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to use a method that the subclasses could override without overriding `__init__()`. Maybe like this:

```
class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # initialization stuff
        self.setup_subclass()
        self.always_do_this_last()

    def setup_subclass(self):
        pass

    def always_do_this_last(self):
        # cleanup stuff

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def setup_subclass(self):
        # intermediate stuff
```

Would that work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of overriding `__init__`, define a method that `SuperClass.__init__` will call.

```
class SuperClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # do some stuff
        self.child_init()
        self.cleanup()

    def cleanup():
        ...

    def child_init(self):
        pass


class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def child_init(self):
        ...
```

You can define `SuperClass.__init_subclass__` to ensure `child_init` is overriden, or use the `abc` module to make `SuperClass.child_init` an abstract method

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1. **Use a different method as your initializer and call `always_do_this_last` afterwards**

   ```
   class SuperClass(object):
       def __init__(self):
           self._init()  # initialize
           self.always_do_this_last()  # clean up

       def _init(self):
           pass # initialization stuff

       def always_do_this_last(self):
           pass # cleanup stuff

   class SubClass(SuperClass):
       def _init(self):
           super()._init()
           # intermediate stuff
   ```
2. **Use a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-metaclass)**

   ```
   class CleanupMeta(type):
       def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
           obj = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
           obj.always_do_this_last()
           return obj

   class SuperClass(metaclass=CleanupMeta):
       def __init__(self):
           pass # initialization stuff

       def always_do_this_last(self):
           pass # cleanup stuff

   class SubClass(SuperClass):
       def __init__(self):
           super().__init__()
           # intermediate stuff
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are more than sufficient. I will add that you might want to have a look at the [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) if you are implementing a class that requires certain member functions to be implemented.

In the example below the parent *requires* the `initialize` and `cleanup` methods to be defined in each child (try removing one of them to verify an error is raised).

```
import abc

class SuperClass(object):

    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        print("Instantiating Class")
        self.initialize()
        self.cleanup()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def initialize(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def cleanup(self):
        pass

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__()

    def initialize(self):
        print("initializing...")

    def cleanup(self):
        print("... cleanup.")


a = SubClass()
```